# Service Worker Background Sync - On rejecting promise - there are no retries from the waitUntil?

Tags: indexeddb, service-worker, background-sync

I am creating a offline first blogging platform which utilises IndexedDB and service workers. The idea here is if the user is offline and trying to send a post - send it in the background. This project is for my dissertation, I have only been looking at promises for a week or so - apologies if it is a simple error!

From my action in react/redux, i'm sending the sync event through successfully.

Below is the code for my sync event handler

```
self.addEventListener('sync', function(event) {
  if (event.tag == 'send_post') {
    //const URL
    console.log('sync from SW - send post');
    //this should try again if promise is rejected
    event.waitUntil(
      openDatabase('Outbox').then( (db) => {
        return databaseGet('posts',db).then( (posts) => {
          return sendAllFromOutbox(posts)
        } )
      } )

    );
  }
});
```

Below is openDatabase - (IndexedDB)

```
    function openDatabase(name) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var version = 10;
        var request = indexedDB.open(name, version);
        var db;
        request.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
          db = e.target.result;
          e.target.transaction.onerror = reject;
        };
        request.onsuccess = function(e) {
          db = e.target.result;
          console.log('OPENED DATABASE');
          resolve(db);
        };
        request.onerror = reject;
      });
    }
```

Below is databaseGet

```
function databaseGet(type,db) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var transaction = db.transaction([type], 'readonly');
    var store = transaction.objectStore(type);
    var request = store.getAll();
    request.onsuccess = function(e) {
      var result = e.target.result;
      resolve(result);
    };
    request.onerror = reject;
  });
}
```

And finally, below is sendAllFromOutbox

```
function sendAllFromOutbox(posts) {
  return fetch('https://stirapi.herokuapp.com/sendPost', {
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(posts)
  })
  .then( (response) => {
    console.log('response from SW sendAllFromOutbox', response);
  } )
  .catch( (err) => {
    console.log('error from SW sendAllFromOutbox',err);
  } )
}
```

From my understanding, if sendAllFromOutbox fails/rejects - it should get called again. But it doesn't seem to be getting called - and therefore is not being sent in the background.

If you would like to check out my repo - it's here https://github.com/georgecook92/Stir.

Thank you!

George

Comment: This isn't your problem, just a general warning: be careful when mixing IDB and promises, they don't always play well together. See the example in https://crbug.com/457409.

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain this a little more? I thought the sendAllFromOutbox function would control whether the function should get called or not? This is just a fetch which takes data from a previous IDB call? Apologies if I misunderstand, new to promises!

Comment: IDB and promises is much better than it used to be. See https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's down to the browser to decide when the failed sync event should be retried. Also, it won't retry infinitely, but you know it's the last attempt via `syncEvent.lastChance` ([spec](https://wicg.github.io/BackgroundSync/spec/#dom-syncevent-lastchance)).

Looking at your code above, `databaseGet` expects `(type,db)`, but you call it `databaseGet('posts')`, so that'll throw an error when you try and access properties of `db`, which is undefined. Chrome's devtools should show this, especially with "break on caught errors".

> The idea here is if the user is offline and trying to send a post - send it in the background

It's best to use background sync regardless of the user's current state. Sure, `navigator.onLine` will tell you if the user is definitely offline, but if `onLine` is true the user still may not have a reliable connection.

- [Guide to background sync](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/12/background-sync?hl=en)
- [Guide to promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/)
- [Promisified IDB](https://www.npmjs.com/package/idb) - same IDB API, but uses promises instead of events

Comment: Thank you!

I used your example online, and changed it to remove the global db and pass it through the chain. I must have copied an older version of the function, apologies! It still appears that there are no retries.  The full code is available in my repo - https://github.com/georgecook92/Stir/blob/master/sw.js

Thank you for the advice regarding using sync on all requests! Appreciate the response!